# Sliding parameters over a ML model

Tags: optimization, optimal

I'm analysing the performance of an algorithm based on neural networks and I have to tune two parameters( number of past days to consider for the turbidity and volume of water flowing) by hand. So considering we've got $X = {x_1,x_2,...,x_n}$ and ${Y=y_1,y_2,...,y_n}$ each having N parameters, doing an exhaustive search for the optimal pair $(x_i,y_j)$ would result in N^2 executions, each taking 20 min therefore lots of time.
Question is: Can I keep one variable constant $X=x_1$ for example and try out all the pairs $(x_1,y_j)$ for $j=1,...,n$ and then find a $y^*$ for which the results are optimal. Then set $Y=y^*$ while trying out the pairs $(x_i,y^*)$ for $i=1,...,n$ ranges and get an optimal solution $x^*$. Can I rightly conclude that $(x^*,y^*)$ gives the best choice of parameters for the model?

Comment: most likely, no... let's say that they are number of layers and neurons... a NN can approximate any function with one layer and enough neurons... keep the layer fixed to 1, optimize the neurons, and you will have 1000 neurons and 1 layer... at this point, using more layers will either do nothing or just make the NN overfits even more (and same the other way around)

Comment: I added some specifications to the question related to the type of parameters (thanks for that) but what if I run the tests for multiple instances with the same parameter values?

Comment: the second parameter doesn't seem to be a hyperparameter...